# Newest Google Script error - Conversion from text/html to application/pdf failed

Tags: html, pdf, google-apps-script

Dears

I've ever write google script as below:

```
var pdfHTML = '<html><head></head><body>test</body></html>';
var blob = HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(pdfHTML);
var pdfName = 'test.pdf';
blob = blob.getBlob();
var pdf = blob.getAs("application/pdf");
DriveApp.createFile(pdf).setName(pdfName).getAs(MimeType.PDF);
```

It works and has been worked over 3 years and it still work on August 9. However, from August 10, the error message suddenly appeared as 'Conversion from text/html to application/pdf failed.'. I am wonder that some libraries in the server have been changed?? I check many papers form Google but didn't find any messages of it. Someone tell me what happened??

Comment: Same issue for me also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### This is a reported bug

> #### [Exception: Conversion from text/html to application/pdf failed](https://issuetracker.google.com/196100674)

Be sure to go and "star" it to let Google know that it affects you.